# Заменить изображение, которое невозможно загрузить

Tags: .htaccess, запрос, img

Всем привет!

На сайте имеется элемент `img`, в котором ссылка на скрипт (на стороннем ресурсе), генерирующий изображение. Когда отключен интернет, скрипт, соответственно, не может выполниться и вместо изображения - пустой квадрат. Можно ли с помощью .htaccess обработать такую ситуацию (когда не получается выполнить запрос к скрипту) и подгружать локальное изображение вместо этого скрипта? Если можно, покажите пример, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, .htaccess (на самом деле апач) способен обработать только локальные запросы. Другое дело, что вы можете заставить бэкенд проксировать этот запрос.